# NLog MailKit reference version

Tags: .net, nlog, mailkit

Am on Nlog Mailkit v3.3 and have Mailkit 2.10.0 referenced in my project

[image]

Unsure why adding the package via NuGet says Version=2.0.0.0 for NLog.Mailkit though the HintPath is calling out the right version.

This all works on my local machine but when deployed to another machine, I see the following in nlog debug trace:
[image]

any idea why MailKit is being referenced back to v2.8? I have obviously included all the DLLs into the base directory of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm just blind/silly.
The assembly references are called out within app.config under the  tags and has specific versions referenced there.

The Nuget installation processes didn't seem to write in the correct values for whatever reason. Though i vaguely recalled that I might have install NLog Mailkit, uninstalled it and then reinstalled it (while the version has transitioned??).

Answer (score 1):

NLog's MailKit API may have been linked with MailKit 2.8.0 and may require that explicit version.

You may need to downgrade your MimeKit/MailKit versions to 2.8.0.

Also as far as NLog 3.3.0 vs 2.0.0 goes, an assembly has multiple versions - there's the *release* version and there's an "API version". Bug fix releases won't generally bump the API version, but they will bump the release version. That may be what is going on with NLog versioning.